# Flooring SQL dates to the first of the month

Tags: sql-server, date

I have dates in the following format:

```
2019-09-01 00:00:00.000
2019-09-02 00:00:00.000
2019-10-22 00:00:00.000
```

I want to floor the dates to get the following:

```
2019-09-01 00:00:00.000
2019-09-01 00:00:00.000
2019-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

How can I do this in a select statement? I tried `DATEPART` but I can only extract the month number.

Answer (score 3):

Another option: Use [`DateFromParts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DateColumn), MONTH(DateColumn), 1) As FirstOfMonth
FROM TableName;
```

I prefer this option over the `EOMonth()` approach suggested in gvee's answer just because it's more readable and doesn't involve any date calculations.

Comment: Yeah - this way is better `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

[`EOMonth()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is your friend!

```sql
SELECT '2019-10-22 00:00:00.000' AS original_value
     , EOMonth('2019-10-22 00:00:00.000') AS end_of_month
     , DateAdd(dd, 1, EOMonth('2019-10-22 00:00:00.000')) AS start_of_next_month
     , DateAdd(mm, -1, DateAdd(dd, 1, EOMonth('2019-10-22 00:00:00.000'))) AS start_of_this_month
;
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the datetime format the same, you can use `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, your_date_column), 0)`

This method counts the months from day 0 (01/01/1900) to your original date, then adds that number of months back to day 0, which returns the beginning of the month

Comment: [DateTime has no format...](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: The request was to get the start of the month, specifically 2019-09-01 00:00:00.000. The other solutions return the beginning of the month, but does not show the milliseconds when selected.

Comment: Well, if the OP wants `datetime` (or even `datetime2`) they can always choose `DateTimeFromParts` or `DateTime2FromParts`... that's still not a "format", though, that's a data type.

Comment: If not a format, then what? A display style? My point is that OP specified that the desired output was 2019-09-01 00:00:00.000. Most of these solutions produced an output of 2019-09-01, which is correct, but displayed differently.

Comment: The difference between `Date` and `DateTime` is the data type itself. The first is a data type that can only contain date information while the last is a data type that can contain date and time information. "Format" has nothing to do with this - when people talk about datetime format what they actually mean is the datetime string representation format - since the datetime value itself is just a binary value (in SQL Server, datetime is stored as an 8 byte integer - It's explained in the blog post I've linked to in my first comment)

Answer (score 0):

There are no straight forward function to find the first day of a month in SQL but one can make use of LAST_DAY() function to calculate it by using these steps:
First, get the last day of the month of a date.
Second, add 1 day to get the first day of the next month using DATE_ADD() function
Third, subtract 1 month to get the first day of the month of the date.
At last, format the date calculated into yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss format as required

The following query illustrates how to get the first day of the month of 2017-07-14.

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY('2017-07-14'),
  INTERVAL 1 DAY),
  INTERVAL - 1 MONTH), 
  "%Y-%m-%d %T") AS first_day;
```

I used the following links to write the answer.
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_day/   ,
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Comment: This is a SQL Server question, there's no `LAST_DAY`. There's `EOMONTH()`